# Count algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, tree, counting

I am looking for an algorithm that counts a given number of states in Python.
There is a string like this: `10?01?011`
with "0, 1, ?" it was made. The question mark can be 0 or 1. The program should enumerate all the states that question marks can have in a string.
For example, in the program '1?01?1' should be printed:

```
110111
110101
100111
100101
```

**Note:** The order does not matter.

I'm thinking about this algorithm but I can't find the optimal algorithm for this problem in Python.Does anyone know how I can create an algorithm for this in Python?
**I am looking for this algorithm in Python without using libraries.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following generator function:

```
from itertools import product  # or use `product` function from below

def states(s):
    for tpl in product("01", repeat=s.count("?")):
        gaps = iter(tpl)  # iterator over the product tuple 
        yield "".join(next(gaps) if c == "?" else c for c in s)

list(states("1?01?1"))
# ['100101', '100111', '110101', '110111']
list(states("???"))
# ['000', '001', '010', '011', '100', '101', '110', '111']
list(states("11?"))
# ['110', '111']
list(states("11"))
# ['11']
```

You form the cartesian product of `"01" x "01" x ... x "01"` for as how many gaps there are. Then you repeatedly fill the gaps with the tuples of the product.

You can write your own `product` function as a drop-in replacement if libraries aren't allowed:

```
def product(pool, repeat=1):
    if not repeat:
        yield []
    else:
        for elmnt in pool:
            for tpl in product(pool, repeat-1):
                yield [elmnt] + tpl
```

There is another implementation of `product` in the [`itertools.product` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).

Comment: thank you for your attention. This program works correctly, but I need to write this algorithm without using libraries. Can you write this algorithm without a library?

Comment: Added a hand-written replacement for `product`

Comment: With the `product` route, I'd do `return map("".join, product(*map({"?": "01"}.get, s, s)))`. That is, handle the question marks *once*, for the `product` input, instead of for every tuple it outputs. Or with `product(*('01' if c == '?' else c for c in s))` to perhaps be simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding by one chacracter at a time:

```python
s = '1?01?1'

ss = ['']
for c in s:
    if c == '?':
        c = '01'
    ss = [s + d for s in ss for d in c]

for s in ss:
    print(s)
```

Output ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYwxDoAgDEX3nuJv1bhIXIyJ4SDGCWNkQUJdPD1SWPzTf21f4/tcd5jmmHIWrGBjR2MNE4nixrzTeSc4@ABZCCX@LLiWW8ttoHEqj0VUaK5gwAG1pdpS@6Hd7US/RXsTkw9PJz1Rzh8)):

```python
100101
100111
110101
110111
```